# Run code after rendering in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, syntax, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I am receiving a HTML code from an external API using AngularJS' `$http.get()` function.

I take this HTML and directly print it into the view: `<div ng-bind-html="vm.text"></div>`

This works fine so far. However, what I can't make work is to execute a script function after rendering. I need to execute `hljs.initHighlighting()` from [highlightJS](https://highlightjs.org) as soon as the received HTML has been injected into the view.

Whatever I tried, it was inperformant or it ran too early. My "best" solution so far:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('libraryView')
    .directive('highlight', function ($timeout) {
            return {
                link: function () {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        hljs.initHighlighting();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            };
        }
    );
```